# Is it okay to pass a large amount of data from a controller to view with viewmodel in MVC3 ?Here'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have code that passes almost 1MB of data from my controller to the view through a viewmodel each time a new page is called. I could optimize this slightly but I am wondering if this would be worth doing as the flow of data is all internal.

Typical of what I am doing in the controller is that I am getting all test results from an Azure datastore and then putting them in a new instance of a class. I am then passing this class and others onto a view. I guess I am not sure. Would the data be passed by reference or would actual data be moved from one place to another?

Anyone have any experience with this side of performance tuning for MVC3?

Here's a made up example. In this example it's nice and easy to pass the "TestData" class and contents to the view but then I just need a couple of items from this class. So I'm wondering if I should add logic in the controller and add fields in the view model for these items or just not bother and move across all the class data including the data I don't need.

```
public class testIndexViewModel
{
    public string   Url { get; set; }
    public PageMeta PageMeta { get; set; }
    public TestData TestData { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: are you displaying all 1MB of the data in your view?

Comment: Good question. If you are displaying all 1MB, then somehow the data has to be retrieved either by passing from the Controller or getting it directly in the view (probably not conventional). But so is displaying 1MB on a single view :)

Comment: Not displaying 1MB. I just pick a few things to display in the view. I could the code simple by passing all of my class data or just pick and choose bits of data to pass from controller to view. I'm just not sure it makes a difference as its all internal within the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ViewModel` class that you create gets added to the `ViewDataDictionary` which your compiled custom `View` class accesses through its base `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ViewModelType>` class. All that means is that I'm pretty sure your `ViewModel` - once it's created - is always accessed by reference, and not copied around the place.

The only performance issue you could come across (I suppose) would be consequent to creating a 1MB object in the first place; how many of these objects are you likely to be creating, and how often?

Personally, I'd not worry about performance optimisation without first load testing and noticing that it's actually causing a problem. If it does and your application only really needs a fraction of the data at any one time, you can build in an optimisation then.

Finally, if you have code in your View to sift through your 1MB of data and pick out the sections you want to display, you might want to only pass the View the data it needs in order to make the code more readable, and better separate the Controller and View's responsibilities.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimization#When_to_optimize

Comment: Thanks Steve. I'll be creating the 1MB object every time the user selects the page as the object containing my data is created from data in the datastore. I'm using azure table storage for this so the data is the contents of one row that is accessed directly by key.

Comment: Fair enough - it'd be quite a common operation by the sound of it, then. From a pure performance view I'd still say it comes down to load testing :)

Answer (score 1):

I would look at this from a user perspective.

How much data will be shown on the screen at anyone time?

If there's too much then there is a risk the data will become meaningless as the user will suffer from information overload.

I would try and use a filtering system of some description, maybe drop down lists for a user to specify as specific set of filters. That way in your controller you can filter down the data so your only returning a small subset of the 1MB set of data.

Alternatively if you want to return all the data I would suggest a more ajax style where only a small subset is returned and as the user scrolls more data is loaded via ajax - similar to how Google images works.

Answer (score 0):

It wont make any difference if you load the 1 mb data and then extract specific data in a new model and pass that to the view. You will use the same amount of memory.  As long as you do not bind against that huge blob in the view